# What is the best way to copy a pandas dataframe from one jupyter notebook to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, copy-paste

Let's say I have created a dataframe in one jupyter notebook:

**In notebook_1:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Now what is the best (easiest, fastest, most reliable, ...) way of moving `df` into another notebook, so that I could work with it there?

**In notebook_2:**

```
df = ... #do something here to load the data from the df in notebook_1
#and now use the df further on
```

I came up with the following ways that (except possibly the last one) all work:

- export to a file and then import using one of the [pandas IO tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) - *probably a good solution for very large dataframes, but otherwise seems unnecessarily complicated*
- use pd.DataFrame.to_clipboard and pd.DataFrame.read_clipboard - *looks good for small dataframes, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stack-overflow-into-python/53692642#53692642) it is not 100% reliable, plus it probably won't work for larger dataframes (?), plus if I rerun the **notebook_2** after I replace the clipboard content with something else, it won't work anymore*
- use pd.DataFrame.to_json and pd.DataFrame.read_json with `orient = 'table'` and `path_or_buf=None` and copy-paste the output - *works well for my case (relatively small dataframe) - the upside is that I can see the imported data directly in the **notebook_2** in plain text and so that notebook becomes self-contained once I first copy the data*
- [copy-paste the whole cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309098/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-cell-from-one-jupyter-notebook-to-another) containing the output of `df` ??? - *I couldn't test whether it copies also the data or just the code - the copy-paste doesn't work for me at all. But I doubt that.*

**Edit - Options mentioned in the comments or answers:**

- the IPython [%store magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) as mentioned by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7093741/chris) - *really simple and nice, only downside is that the notebook_2 will not be self-contained*

But I would like to know if there are other possible methods and what are the advantages, disadvantages, caveats, ...

**I am interested more about insights, comparisons etc. than just one way how to do it** (unless there is one, clearly the best, way that works perfectly in all scenarios and has no disadvantages).

Thanks.

Comment: The way I solved this was by pickling the df to disk, and in the other notebook I'd load it in the beginning. This allows me to start/stop jupyter (use case was in my own computer), and even have versioning, allowing me to use a previous version of the data. I chose pickle because the files aren't huge (max 15 MB), it was all in my computer, and I save other python objects too. Pickle was the solution for me, but it's neither the [most secure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), nor [performant solution](https://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share data between IPython Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621414/share-data-between-ipython-notebooks)

Comment: @Chris: The %store magic as mentioned in your link is an option (pretty neat one, at least for some cases) that I didn't know of. Thank you. However this doesn't answer the question completely. For instance it has the downside that notebook_2 will not be self-contained (will depend on the state of the IPython database) - this may be a problem in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

export your dataframe to the disk using

`df.to_csv('your_name.csv')`

now go to another notebook and read it using the

`pd.read_csv('your_name.csv')`

Comment: I mentioned this option already in my question. But it seems unnecessary to use a local file for this...